# Difficulty line up my Navigation Links and Logo with Responsive Nav Plugin

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I am using the http://responsive-nav.com/ plugin to create my navigation bar, but running into an issue with having the links and logo line up horizontally. I am currently trying to float my links to the right, but they still appear on a level below my image. Is there a better way to do this?

Desktop Image:

[image: Desktop Image]

Mobile Image:

[image: Mobile Image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>

<body>


    <header>
    <div id="navigation-container">
    <div id="nav-logo">
        <a href="/"><img src="images/lvc-logo.png"></a>
    </div>
    <nav class="nav-collapse" id="navigation-links">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/about">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/events">EVENTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/media">MEDIA</a></li>
                </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
</header>

    <script>
      var navigation = responsiveNav(".nav-collapse", {
        insert: "before"
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*! responsive-nav.js 1.0.32 by @viljamis */

#navigation-container {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#nav-logo img {

  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

#navigation-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5cf79b;
}

.nav-collapse ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.nav-collapse li {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}



.js .nav-collapse {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  max-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  zoom: 1;
}

.nav-collapse.opened {
  max-height: 9999px;
}

.disable-pointer-events {
  pointer-events: none !important;
}

.nav-toggle {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: #5cf79b;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .js .nav-collapse {
    position: relative;
  }
  .js .nav-collapse.closed {
    max-height: none;
  }
  .nav-toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  #navigation-links ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;

  }

  #navigation-links li {
    display: inline;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add **float** to the containers and **display** menu elements as `inline-block`.

```js
var navigation = responsiveNav(".nav-collapse", {
        insert: "before"
      });
```

```css
/*! responsive-nav.js 1.0.32 by @viljamis */

#navigation-container {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#nav-logo img {

  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

#navigation-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5cf79b;
}

.nav-collapse ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.nav-collapse li {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}



.js .nav-collapse {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  max-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  zoom: 1;
}

.nav-collapse.opened {
  max-height: 9999px;
}

.disable-pointer-events {
  pointer-events: none !important;
}

.nav-toggle {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: #5cf79b;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .js .nav-collapse {
    position: relative;
  }
  .js .nav-collapse.closed {
    max-height: none;
  }
  .nav-toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  #navigation-links ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;

  }

  #navigation-links li {
    display: inline;

  }

}

#nav-logo { float: left; }
#navigation-links { float: right; }
#navigation-links ul li { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<header>
    <div id="navigation-container">
    <div id="nav-logo">
        <a href="/"><img src="images/lvc-logo.png"></a>
    </div>
    <nav class="nav-collapse" id="navigation-links">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/about">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/events">EVENTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/media">MEDIA</a></li>
                </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```